# My knees hurt after I run and my feet point out or knees point in

Tags: running, pain, knees

Short version: My knees point in when my feet point straight. This makes it hurt when I run.

I'm currently 16. In 9th grade, I switched out of my public school to an independent study one. It's like home schooling, but I meet with a teacher once a week for assignments and do everything myself. It was half way through the year that I switched. I had been running in PE that year and never had any problems. I had finished PE, so it wasn't until a while later when I started running for my own health and not for school. I stretched properly and started off small, but my knees hurt when I stopped running. For a month or two I built up to three miles of slow jogging, but my knees would still hurt.

I started looking online and read something about crows feet, or a similarly named condition. Basically, my feet and knees aren't aligned properly. If my feet point forward, my knees point inward and will touch if I bend them. If my knees point forward, my feet point out. I hadn't noticed this before, but I wasn't looking either, so I don't know how long my legs have been like that.

I talked briefly with a friend of the family who also happens to be a personal trainer. He said that my thighs were a bit weak and showed me an exercise where I sit against a wall and have to strain my muscles to keep myself up. He also said to ice my knees, as there's probably swelling. I did both for two months and saw no change, so I switched to squats. I did those for a while and still didn't notice anything.

Does anyone know anything about this? What can I do?

Comment: Have you met a doctor/orthopedic about this? Did you ever made a complete physical check? I am not a doctor, but maybe meeting one can give you another solution.

Comment: Agree with the above.  See an orthopedic, discuss the problem and see if physical therapy is an option.  If you have weak thighs you want someone who understand HOW they are weak and WHY.  A PT can show you how to ensure the proper muscles are as string as they need to be.  They'll also ensure you don't do something that inhibits the good things about the form you currently have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the exact same condition. When I was really young I always "knelt" with my bum on the floor and my legs out to the sides (rather than underneath me). Over the years this contorted my legs and knees.  A doctor told my mother I might not be able to run at all. Ever since, when my knees are parallel pointing forward, my feet angle outwards at probably 35 degrees.

I wear down my shoes unevenly, due to this angle in my feet. I always hating running (especially on hard surfaces) due to the knee pain and shin splints.

Then I heard about "barefoot/minimal" running and decided to try it. Taking away the cushy and impact-deadening sneakers forced me to listen to my body and my legs and feet did what came naturally. I have *no more pain* in my knees or shins even when I run more than 5K. My feet still point outwards, but I've developed a more natural gait that fits my body, as a result of listening to my body. I run all the time in my vibrams, and actually enjoy running on asphalt now!

Comment: I had looked into the five fingers/barefoot type running and figured that it wouldn't help much as I'd either be running with my knees pointing inward or my feet angled out, either one putting undue stress on my joints. I suppose I'll give them a try though before giving up running altogether. Do you run on the sidewalk, or go to a local park or something?

Comment: @somatic How much running did you do and how long did it take for you to develop a more natural gait?

Comment: @MattChan, I was only running 1-3 miles. I'm unsure what you mean by the second part. I wasn't able to align my knees and feet while running, but I had been keeping my feet pointing forward, meaning that my knees would be pointing inward.

Comment: @Walkerneo I read over your sentence a little quickly there, but I was asking how long it took you to adapt to your barefoot/minimal running until you stopped feeling pain in your knees as you said.

Comment: When you run barefoot, your gait changes *immediately*, because it's too painful to run like you normally do in shoes. The amazing thing is, your body naturally knows what to do, and with the added sensory input from your feet, automatically (in order to avoid discomfort) changes your gait. You're basically springing off the balls of your feet the whole time. Expect to be rather slow at first. I just ran around the block, on the sidewalk or in the middle of the street. You can start out completely barefoot on a treadmill to see how it changes your gait.

Comment: As for knee pain - *it was gone from the very first run*. When you're not striking your heel, you're not pounding your legs or joints. Your whole foot/ankle/leg becomes a big, natural shock absorber (now that you're using it the way evolution intended). From that first barefoot run onwards, my limiting factor is not knee pain (either during or afterwards), but cardio endurance and calf strength. I worked myself up to running 5k's in under 29 minutes, and not once, even after pushing myself hard in a race do I ever have knee pain. My legs might be jelly, but absolutely *no* knee pain.

Comment: FYI - expect to experience some *serious* calf soreness at first. Heel-strike running doesn't work your calf/achilles area near as much as forefoot-striking. This is normal. I could barely walk the day after my first race. But this is completely different from joint/knee pain. Gentle, consistent training will strengthen your muscles (whereas no amount of training will fix your bum knee).

Comment: @MattChan, Sorry about my last comments, I thought you were talking to me. Somatic has gotten back about the knee pain though.

Comment: @somatic, I've tried running on the balls of my feet with my heels NEVER touching the ground while running. I don't understand how running barefoot would be different. It also doesn't address the problem that my knees need to point inward when my feet are forward.

Comment: If you can truly discipline yourself to only run on the balls of your feet with shoes on (which is what sprinters basically do), then yes, it would be very similar to barefoot running.

The trick is, with cushy shoes, it's just too easy to let the shoe take the shock (especially as you get more tired). Barefoot/minimal shoes force you to maintain the right stride.

Comment: As for your knees vs. your feet - it simply doesn't matter where they point. My right foot angles outwards even more than my left when I run. Doesn't cause any problems. Barefoot running won't necessarily change the orientation of your knees or feet - just help you run *healthier*. You don't need them to line up just so in order to stop your knees from hurting. Don't try to force them to line up when you run - point them where it feels most comfortable and natural, and let the rest of your body adjust.

Comment: @Walkerneo - No problem. I also responded to your comment thinking you were somatic. Whoops. :)

Answer (score 1):

Before seeing a doctor, self diagnosing always makes things look worse than they may be.  I would suggest you go to a specialist running store, with trained staff.  Ask the running clubs in your area for a recommendation.

I experienced problems with my feet whenever running longer than 5km.  The staff at the running store looked at my gait running on their short track and recommended a different set of shoes.  First run out with the new shoes I did 12km without any pain.

Properly trained staff would also suggest you visit a doctor should things look wrong to them.